Movie on HBO early 80s, animated, similar style to last unicorn
I was like 8 to 10, and I don't remember much.  But it was an animated movie that played on HBO, similar style in animation to the last unicorn, may have been manga or anime.  All I remember is there was like a castle or fortress, I thought it was floating, it had a black and white tile floor.  There was a hero of course, and I think maybe a princess, and the villain or one of the villains was this mysterious being, and I think there may have been a character in a top hat.  The music was the scene of the tile floor was kind of weird, very synthesizerish.  I know it's not much, but I loved this movie as a kid and that's all I can remember.

Welcome to the community. Any other plot details, like events where the here and villain interact? I hope you like it here.

A couple of questions: 1) Was the movie in English? (The version that you saw, anyway?) 2) Were there any musical song-and-dance numbers?

This might be my own obsession talking, but I believe you might be looking for Jack and the Beanstalk (1974), original name  ジャックと豆の木 (Jack to mame no ki).

It's an animated musical version of the Jack and the Beanstalk story, produced in Japan, but released to US theaters in a dubbed format.  The action mostly takes place on a floating castle.  
There is a musical chase sequence featuring the checkerboard floor.

At one point the giant (named Tulip) wears a top hat, as he is going to be marrying the princess.
The music was a blast, if a bit strange. I've been trying to find the movie on DVD for years, though it is available on YouTube.
